# Rest Call without using Connected App

Tags: authentication, rest

We have a REST call that one of our systems is making to Salesforce but we do not have a Connected App set up.  I cannot for my life figure out how to do this without a connected App that uses the Client_Id and Client_Secret but somehow this REST service we have is getting connected to an executed.

(Eventually I will be able to ask the developer from the other system but he's out the next 2 weeks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the possibility of a public web service, you can use **any** session ID with the REST API. So, you might obtain a session ID from:

- OAuth with a connected app
- SOAP login
- Force.com Canvas
- Send it as an attribute in a SAML Assertion

There are probably more alternatives, that I can't think of right now.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented webhooks style rest based services without the use of connected app.

This can be done by creating a RestResource Apex class, and then exposing this through an unauthenticated public site. You would need to make the apex class available through setup->sites->[site]->PublicAccessSettings->ApexClassAccess

So if you are trying to find such a service in your org: Check your sites Apex Class Access, and then examine each of the classes to see if any are RestResources

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my_contact_service/*')
   global without sharing class ContactWebhook {
   //some http implementation 
}
```